# Is there a way to restrict foreign keys references to another column putting custom rules on this references?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-modeling

I have three tables that are all user types of my system: `master`, `unit`, and `employee`.

Basically, all of these tables have a column that refers to `user(id)` (all these tables have a `user` row too with general data).

The principal point of this question is the `employee` table, which has a column called `employer_id` (who is the employer of this employee) where refers to `user(id)`. My issue is I want to restrict the `employer_id` foreign key reference only to `master` xor `unit`, not to the both, and not to users that are neither master and neither unit. But the fact that the `employer_id` refers to `user(id)` allows that any type of user of the system can be an employer of this employee.

Is there a way to restrict foreign keys table references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a trigger before insert/update that will check whether exists an employee whose `user_id` matches the value of `employer_id`. If such a record exists, then throw an exception. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using triggers too, but I wasn't sure of doing that. Thanks btw

Comment: Thank you, sir! :D